# Rails validates exclusion wont fail on selected words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a initiative model, within the model i have:

```
validates :initiative_type, inclusion: { in: %w(Interactive Subactive), message: "Initiative type is incorrect" }
validates :initiation_date, exclusion: { in: %w(format date_out_of_bounds), message: "Initiation date is incorrect" }
```

if i then open the console and go,

```
i = Initiative.new
i.initiative_type = 'Interactive'
i.initiation_date = 'format'
i.save
  => true
i.initiation_date
  => nil

i.initiative_type = 'monkey'
i.save
  => false
i.errors.messages
=> {
  :initiative_type => [
    [0] "Initiative type is incorrect"
  ]
}
```

Its not showing the errors at all for initiation dates. The column for the `initiation_date` is a date/time format within the db. i have a service that figures out if a date from excel is in the correct format and then converts it to a date. If its not in the correct format i have it send the value as `'format'`, or if its an unreasonable date like something 1000 years from now i sends the value as `'date_out_of_bounds'`.

but why is the validation not catching the words i have used within the exclusion block? All the things within the inclusion block works fine, If its not included it raises the error just fine.

**Additional info**

I found the documentation on exclusion here [RailsGuides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#exclusion), inclusion is number 2.6 just below exclusion.

Comment: When you assign a invalid value to a date time attribute (i.e., `i.initiation_date = 'format'`), it will just assign a `nil`.
Therefore, the exclusion validation is always valid.

Comment: mmm.. well thats problematic. well thank you. ill start looking at a different way to do this then.

Comment: If you can have the actual date provided to the model, you could just have the same logic used to assign the `'format'` and `'date_out_of_bounds'` to validate the attribute.